# Segmentation fault signal 11

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have been solving a problem for finding the total no. of for a getting a given sum total amount of money for user given denomination

```
#include<stdio.h>
int denomination(int amt,int coin[],int n){
    //int sum=0;
    if(amt==0){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(amt<0)return 0;
    else{
        int include=denomination(amt-coin[n-1],coin,n);
        int exclude=denomination(amt,coin,n-1);
        return include+exclude;
    }

}

int main()
{
    //  Insert your code here.
    int t,amt,n,coin[100];
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    scanf("%d",&coin[i]);
    }
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){
        scanf("%d",&amt);
        int a=denomination(amt,coin,n);
        printf("%d\n",a);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I implemented this code and am getting code segmentation fault

Comment: This is more of a c code than c++

Comment: What happens when n is >= 100? You should sanitize your inputs.

Answer (score 2):

This line causes the problem: `int exclude=denomination(amt,coin,n-1);` because amt is still as it is and `n` decreases with no base case. Imagine that `n` became `0` and you have to access `coins[n-1]` in this call: `denomination(amt-coin[n-1],coin,n);`

Please, reconsider your base cases again.